# Does "make javaScript and CSS External" mean to use JavaScript to load CSS and JS?

Tags: language-agnostic

> Make javaScript and CSS External

[Source](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#external).

Does that mean I should use JavaScript to load JavaScript and CSS files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it means link them with `link` and `script` elements so they can be downloaded once and cached for subsequent requests.

#### Good example.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/css/common.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/common.js"></script>
```

If you include the code and styles inline, they must be downloaded per request.

#### Bad example.

```
<style type="text/css">
...
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
```

However, loading assets with JavaScript can often be a good idea too.

Comment: Thanks . But is it same as use normal?. I don't see what it diffent from normal. Can you add a example about don't use css and js external .

Comment: @meo I added a second example.

Comment: Thank a lot. In fact, i almost don't use second example , too.